# force vue to recognize a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I face a stupid situation where a component is properly instanciated when call directly.
But If this component is call Within another component from another project, it failed.

```
<template>
    <vue-tel-input-vuetify /> //this Totally work
    <phone-field /> //this raise the error. -> Unknown custom element: <vue-tel-input-vuetify>"
</template>
<script>
  import { PhoneField } from 'anotherProjectUsingYarnLint';
  import { VueTelInputVuetify } from 'vue-tel-input-vuetify';
  export default {
    components: {
      PhoneField
      VueTelInputVuetify,
    },
}
```

The Phone field does only contain a `<vue-tel-input-vuetify />` tag. and work properly on the other Project.

Therefor the question is: Is there a way to force Vue to recognize the component ? a way to declare the component global maybe ?

**Edit** : the PhoneField Component

```
<template>
    <vue-tel-input-vuetify />
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
  import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  Vue.use(Vuetify);
  @Component<PhoneField>({
    //stuff
  })
  export default class PhoneField extends Vue {
   // stuff
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Pls share complete code for your `PhoneField` component...

Comment: This means that "vue-tel-input-vuetify" component wasn't properly registered in the app. Package documentation should clearly say what's needs to be done. It won't be recognized by magic.

Answer (score 0):

First line of the (let's call it `Main`) component template works because the `VueTelInputVuetify` is properly registered. But this registration is only [local](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration) - it means that the `VueTelInputVuetify` will be recognized only in this `Main` component

If you want to use it inside `PhoneField` component, you must register it again here (`import` + `components:{ VueTelInputVuetify }`)

Or you can register your component [globaly](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration) (for example in your main `app.js` file)